# Alphabetic comparison - why is a less than b?

Tags: swift, string-comparison

This may be a really dumb question but why does `a > b` equal `false`?
Why is "a" less than "b"? Is it because "a" is 1, "b" is 2, "c" is 3 and so on?

Comment: [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: The "<" can be used to mean "comes before", as in *a* comes before *b* in the alphabet. You need to be careful though, as uppercase letters come before lowercase letters in ASCII, so "Z" < "a".

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's not ASCII, it's Unicode.

Comment: Awesome, that clears it, thank you very much for your help